# Gunzip/gzip compression ratio?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, amazon-dynamodb

**Situation:**

I have some string that can be at most 240,000 characters long. I store this string in AWS DynamoDB. Since DynamoDB uses UTF-8 encoding and each String can be at most 400 KB, worst case scenario my string would be 240,000 char * 4 bytes/char = 960,000 bytes, which exceeds the limit of 409,600 bytes.

I did some testing on compressing strings. Based on the result, it seems like 1 byte UTF-8 character strings can be compressed by 25% using gzip and 2-3 byte UTF-8 character strings can be compressed by 60% using gzip.

I used this link to compress string to binary: http://www.txtwizard.net/compression

**Question:**

How much can I compress using gzip? What's the worst case and average case? (How much it can compress for 4 byte UTF-8 strings? 1 byte UTF-8 strings?)

If I have this 240,000 characters long string, can I always compress it to less than 400,000 bytes?